# Mysql: please help add product location in inventory system

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,

I am finished a project with an inventory system which has the following tables,
**tbl_category**
.cati_id
.category

**tbl_product**
.pid
.product_name
.pcategory
.pstock
.product_image

**tbl_invoice**
.invoice_id
.customer_name
.order_date
.total

I have included the tables I think relevant to this question.I have been tasked to include
the location for each product, however I am not sure if need to create a table for the locations
or simply add a column in the tbl_product.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know the history of a product? Where was it yesterday? How did it get to the customer? Who handled it?

Comment: @Kiko , Not really history is not relevant . Basically I need to know the location to facilitate the stock counting (taking) process.

Comment: In that case just one field in the *tbl_product* called .plocation would do, I think. However, what if one product is present in multiple locations? Can your schema cope with that?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware , thanks

Comment: If a product can be stored in multiple locations, there should be a separate table linking locations to `productId`s